# opencv .dll files not found

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, opencv, codeblocks

I am running windows 8 64 bit and using Code::Blocks as well as Eclipse as IDE for OpenCV v.2.4.4.

I am following the online tutorial at http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html#basic-linear-transform

Whenever I include `.dll.a` files in `opencv\build\x64\mingw\lib\` as well as required headers in `opencv\build\include` in my IDE settings and corresponding `opencv\build\x64\mingw\bin` in my PATH variable, I get compile time errors about undefined reference to opencv functions.

Whenever I include the corrosponding 32 bit dll files in my IDE settings and set 32 bit dll files' path in my PATH variable, the program compiles fine. But, when I open the .exe file, it says that '`libopencv_core244.dll` is missing from your computer. Re-install the application.' The PATH variable being set correctly, I don't understand the problem..

I am digging up about this on the web as much as I can but still unable to fix this...please help...

Comment: Stick with the 32bit DLLs in your IDE settings. Just be **absolutely certain** that Windows` PATH environment variable points to whatever directory holds `libopencv_core244.dll`. If that doesn't solve the problem, copy OpenCV's DLL to the same folder as your compiled **.exe** and try to open it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rebooting after updating the PATH variable worked!